# Why pod lib create does not make directory correctly for cocoapod?

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I wanna make a component for iOS,iPhone via **COCOAPODS**.
So in terminal i write this code:

```
pod lib create myprojectname
```

and pod made a new xcode project called *myprojectname*.(It's OK)
Generally when i go to pod and expand it, there must be a directory like this:

> Development Pods/myprojectname/myprojectname/Classes/ReplaceMe.swift

But it's not there.

[image]

What the problem whit my way?

I tried this way already and not got any problem like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the project folder using Finder you'll see that the `Classes` folder is actually generated and `ReplaceMe.swift` is inside of it.

**It's just Xcode that doesn't show the folder in the project navigator.** Not sure why but you can always just remove the folder and recreate it from Xcode.

Answer (score -1):

Why are you creating pod using `pod lib create myprojectname` instead try  `pod init` from the project directory, then you will find podfile add the corresponding pod you want to add & save that file. Then from that directory in terminal try `pod install` in that case this will not happen.